# Ideal Way of performing CRUD Operations in OOPS via PHP

Tags: php, oop, crud

I was just starting out with OOPS in PHP for my project. And wanted to ensure that i learn the correct OOP methodologies for a project.

My Class Looks like this:

```
class user
{
    //class variables

    public function __construct
    {
        //initializes all class variables to null
    }

    public function setById($id)  
    {
        //Queries Database for row matching $id and sets the class variables with
        the same values as returned in result
    }

    public function setValues($array)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key = $value;       
        }   
    }

    public function update()
    {
        //updates the database table from the class variables
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        //deletes the row matching the class variable called id
    }
}
```

Now for an update operation:

1) I will first declare the object.
2) then call SetById() function with the parameter as the id of the row i wish to update. That will set all the present values from the database.
3) then will call setValues() function to update the values in class variables.
4) then will call update function to update the database row from the values of class variables.

Is this the correct way to update in OOP methodology?

For a delete operation:

1) I will first declare the object.
2) then call SetById() function with the parameter as the id of the row i wish to update. That will set all the present values from the database.
3) then will call delete function to delete the row matching id in the class variables.

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

That depends. Are you planning on doing anything with that user? (Other than displaying it)?

If you don't, Go for the **[Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)** pattern. If you do have some sort of logic involved with users, go for the **[Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)** pattern.

The main difference is that with Table Data Gateway, the focus is on the table (One gateway object per table, that allows you to do operations on that table). With the Data Mapper however, the focus is on the Domain Objects (i.e. the `User` objects), and there's generally one mapper class per domain class. (i.e. `User` and `UserMapper`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will look into the two patterns you have linked here. But my question is that: does my code violate any OOP principles? It is correct according to OOP methodology?

Comment: @KanishkDudeja: Yes. It's almost never the `User` object's job to save itself to permanent storage (database). There's almost always a separation between the two.